# How to call $(this) inside a function within a function?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a `delay()` or `setTimeout` inside a `function()` that uses `$(this)`. I want to use `$(this)` because this script is ran for each table row, so it has to target the same row. I can achieve this by using `.closest()` etc. However I'm just having difficulty calling `$(this)` inside a function within a function.

If I understand where I'm going wrong it's the fact that `$(this)` would be trying to get itself from `setTimeout`? If so how can I have it so I can use the same $(this) that I have been using?

**Code in question:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $(this).closest("td").next().find('.tabledit-save-button').click();
}, 2000)
```

**Full Code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $('.tabledit-view-mode').on( 'click', function(e){
            $(this).closest("td").next().find('.tabledit-edit-button').click();
            $(this).find(".tabledit-input").val("completed");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).closest("td").next().find('.tabledit-save-button').click();
            }, 2000)
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try setting variable with `$(this)` value and use it inside `setTimeout` function. Like this : `var that = $(this);setTimeout(function(){that.closest....`

Comment: @YasharAliabasi thanks you are correct :-)

Comment: If my post was helful then please flag my comment.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take that in a variable and use that variable instead of `$(this)`, like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $('.tabledit-view-mode').on( 'click', function(e){
            var current = $(this);
            current.closest("td").next().find('.tabledit-edit-button').click();
            current.find(".tabledit-input").val("completed");
            setTimeout(function() {
                current.closest("td").next().find('.tabledit-save-button').click();
            }, 2000)
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @miliancheda your answer was very clear and example showed me exactly how to achieve this. :-)